# Wi-Fi is missing on Windows...while Keyboard and mouse wont work on Linux(only Touchpad)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, windows-11, device-manager

I have this weird issue where my Wi-Fi and Bluetooth is missing from setting, while in Linux, even the Keyboard and Mouse won't work to control the Laptop. I have a Legion 7i with Intel Core i7 10750H, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, RTX 2070 8GB VRAM. I also posted a screenshot of my Device Manager

[image: Screenshot of Device Manager]

Is it maybe because I slept the laptop while is connected to the charger and then unplug the charger then wake the laptop up again? Because since then my Wi-Fi is problematic in Windows 11 is it a bug from Windows 11? Because whenever I want to sleep my laptop I have to slept it twice (sleep it once, then move the cursor to wake up the display and sleep it again then it worked)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Start by (1) update UEFI; (2) disable Fast Boot; (3) in Windows disable Fast Startup, a must when dual-booting. Finally, your unnamed Linux needs to be running a very recent kernel, 5.13 or newer recommended and you need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers AND find a way to SIGN those drivers (distro dependent, Debian/Ubuntu uses MOKutil) because you CAN'T disable Secure Boot due to Windows 11 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to install non-free drivers for your stuff in "linux"
Lenovo used to be reasonably good at supporting linux, ie, drivers available from their website.

As for windows, just, good luck.
I'm more surprised when it works than when it doesn't.